# JavaScript Button to href so I can call it from my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built a dialog in Javascript that has 3 buttons like this:

```
            buttons: {
            'Spara': function() {

                if (!validate()) {
                    alert('Procent måste vara mellan 0-100');
                    return false;
                }

                locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Update/?";

                locstring += '&projectId=' + $('#projectList').val();
                locstring += '&startDate=' + $('#startDate').val();
                locstring += '&endDate=' + $('#endDate').val();
                locstring += '&pct=' + $('#pct').val();

                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid != "") {
                    locstring += '&id=' + sid;
                    //locstring = "/Delete/" + sid;
                }
                //window.location = locstring;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: locstring,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //alert(locstring);
                        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        ReloadTable();
                    }
                });


            },
            'Avbryt': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Ta bort': function() {
                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid != "") {
                    locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Delete/" + sid;
                    //locstring += '&delete=true&id=' + sid;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: locstring,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                            ReloadTable();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

However, can I turn these buttons into some kind of href so I can can call them in my html code like this? `<a href="javascript:OpenDialog()" class="btn btn-primary">`

Because I would like to place them around in the dialog that pops up and I would like to style them differently. Thanks.

Comment: What about the `onclick` attribute? `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OpenDialog()" class="btn btn-primary">`

Comment: The problem is not to open the dialog, it opens just fine. The 3 buttons I make in my javascript I would like to call them from 3 different buttons. Like it is now the javascript will just place them in my dialog but I want to assign them to 3 buttons my self so I replace them and give them styles.

Comment: I don't think I follow, you want to call buttons by clicking on other buttons?

Comment: The javascript now generates the buttons for me, and it places them were I do want them. So I can to have the options to have make my own button in html and so something like this: `<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Spara">
        Spara
    </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use of custom data attribute as --

```
<button data-href="--"  class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
```

Comment: So it would be something like `<button data-href="Spara"  class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>` ? Dosen't seem to work

Comment: I do not think that would work very good as they are buttons in dialog and not just some value I want to show up.